# destruct tactic failed, can only eliminate into Prop

Tags: lean

Given a custom type to represent embeddings from type b to a:

```
inductive Embedding (b a:Sort u) : Sort u
| Embed : forall (j:b -> a), (forall (x y:b), j x = j y -> x = y) -> Embedding
```

I am attempting to define a function `restrict` which given a relation `r:a -> a -> Prop`
and an embedding `e:Embedding b a` returns a relation on `b`

```
def restrict {a b:Sort u} (r:a -> a -> Prop) (e:Embedding b a) (x y: b) : Prop :=
  begin
   destruct e, -- error 
  end
```

I am not able to deconstruct my embedding to get access to the underlying injection.

```
 destruct tactic failed, recursor 'Embedding.cases_on' can only eliminate into Prop
```

Doing the same thing in Coq works fine:

```
(* There is an injection j:b -> a, i.e. b is a subset of a                      *)
Inductive Embedding (b a:Type) : Type :=
| Embed : forall (j:b -> a), (forall (x y:b), j x = j y -> x = y) -> Embedding b a
.

Arguments Embed {b} {a}.

(* Restricting relation r on a to subset b                                      *)
Definition restrict (a b:Type) (r:a -> a -> Prop) (e:Embedding b a) (x y:b) 
    : Prop :=
        match e with
        | Embed j _ => r (j x) (j y)
        end.

Arguments restrict {a} {b}.
```

I would be grateful if anyone could suggest something to go round the issue. I am familiar with the Coq restriction of not being able to deconstruct a term of sort `Prop` when having a goal of Sort `Set` or `Type i`, so would understand a similar restriction in Lean, but this does seem to be the issue here. I have tried to make `Embedding` being an inductive predicate (so returning `Prop` rather than `Sort u`) but this did not resolve the error.

I am keen to translate my Coq developments as a way to learn Lean, so would be very happy to break this hurdle :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is `Embedding` has type `Sort u`. `Sort 0` is `Prop`, so if `a` and `b` are `Prop`, then `Embedding` is a `Prop`. When inductive types are `Prop`, their recursor can usually only be used to prove `Prop`s and not to define anything in `Type`. You have to make sure that `Embedding` cannot be a `Prop`

The solution is to use

```
inductive Embedding (b a:Sort u) : Sort (max 1 u)
```

or alternatively

```
inductive Embedding (b a:Type u) : Type u
```